# Contact form displays PHP in browser after removing iframe

Tags: php, iframe, contact-form

I want to reuse/restyle a php form I had used before, but utilizes an iframe calling the php file. I was informed this is bad practice and to discontinue using iframes; However, when I moved the php to my html page, the php code displays in the form's text fields.

I checked a few pages worth of php threads here, and it seems like the problem is usually forgetting to close php tags or the host doesn't support php. I didn't alter the php itself from the working version, and my host supports PHP version 5.3.6.

EDIT: changing the file to a .php cleared the php in browser, but the form will not send.

The PHP displaying in the text fields are as follows:

```
<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['name'] : '' ?>
<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['email'] : '' ?>
<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['message'] : '' ?>
```

The Contact.html Page Code:

```
    <div id="contact-form" class="clearfix">

<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
include("spam_check.php");
?>
            <h2> You can contact us by filling out the form below.</h2>
            <?php
            //init variables
            $cf = array();
            $sr = false;

            if(isset($_SESSION['cf_returndata'])){
                $cf = $_SESSION['cf_returndata'];
                $sr = true;
            }
            ?>
            <ul id="errors" class="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? 'visible' : ''; ?>">
                <li id="info">There were some problems with your form submission:</li>
                <?php 
                if(isset($cf['errors']) && count($cf['errors']) > 0) :
                    foreach($cf['errors'] as $error) :
                ?>
                <li><?php echo $error ?></li>
                <?php
                    endforeach;
                endif;
                ?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['real'])) {
  // error condition, redisplay form
}
?>
            </ul>
            <p id="success" class="<?php echo ($sr && $cf['form_ok']) ? 'visible' : ''; ?>">Thanks for your message! We will get back to you ASAP!</p>
            <form method="post" action="process.php">
                <label for="name">Name: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['name'] : '' ?>" placeholder="Your Name" required autofocus />

                <label for="email">Email: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['email'] : '' ?>" placeholder="yourname@example.com" required />

                <label for="message">Message: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your message must be greater than 20 characters." required data-minlength="20"><?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['message'] : '' ?></textarea>

<label style="display:block;position:absolute;left:-9999px" class="real">
  Please leave this checkbox blank
  <input type=checkbox name=real value=1>
</label>

                <span id="loading"></span>
                <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="submit-button" />
                <p id="req-field-desc"><span class="required">*</span> indicates a required field</p>          
            </form>

            <?php unset($_SESSION['cf_returndata']); ?>
        </div>
```

Process.php:

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST) ){

    //form validation vars
    $formok = true;
    $errors = array();

    //sumbission data
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $date = date('d/m/Y');
    $time = date('H:i:s');

    //form data
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    //validate form data

    //validate name is not empty
    if(empty($name)){
        $formok = false;
        $errors[] = "You have not entered a name";
    }

    //validate email address is not empty
    if(empty($email)){
        $formok = false;
        $errors[] = "You have not entered an email address";
    //validate email address is valid
    }elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $formok = false;
        $errors[] = "You have not entered a valid email address";
    }

    //validate message is not empty
    if(empty($message)){
        $formok = false;
        $errors[] = "You have not entered a message";
    }
    //validate message is greater than 20 charcters
    elseif(strlen($message) < 20){
        $formok = false;
        $errors[] = "Your message must be greater than 20 characters";
    }

    //send email if all is ok
    if($formok){
        $headers = "From: name@email.com" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

        $emailbody = "<p>You have received a new message from the form on your website.</p>
                      <p><strong>Name: </strong> {$name} </p>
                      <p><strong>Email Address: </strong> {$email} </p>
                      <p><strong>Message: </strong> {$message} </p>
                      <p>This message was sent from the IP Address: {$ipaddress} on {$date} at {$time}</p>";

        mail("name@email.com","New Enquiry",$emailbody,$headers);

    }

    //what we need to return back to our form
    $returndata = array(
        'posted_form_data' => array(
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'telephone' => $telephone,
            'enquiry' => $enquiry,
            'message' => $message
        ),
        'form_ok' => $formok,
        'errors' => $errors
    );


    //if this is not an ajax request
    if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest'){
        //set session variables
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['cf_returndata'] = $returndata;

        //redirect back to form
        header('location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

View the page source - is the rest of the PHP code there as well? If php wasn't working properly, then ALL the code would show up, not just a few bits that are inside a form field.

You say you moved it to a "html file". Is that "somefile.html"? Remember that generally .html is NOT set to be parsed by PHP by the webserver. Try renaming it to "somefile.php".

Comment: Yes, I can view all php in the source. I changed the file to .php and everything seems to display fine now, though I fired a test email I never received. I had originally searched to see if implanting php in a html page was alright. The results I came across simply said to always include <?php ?> Does it matter that I am still calling html doctype at the beginning?

Comment: has nothing to do with the doctype, and everything with the fact that the webserver will **NOT** pass .html files through the PHP interpreter unless you tell it to.

Comment: Alright. I'm just trying to figure out why the form now displays correctly but will not submit. Added Process.php to original post. I'm wondering if I should just try to keep everything in its own php file and just insert an action to call the php file in html form? I'll try this as soon as I get home.

Comment: You can use anything you want as an action, e.g. post to a JPG, but nothing much will happen. there's no reason you can't have a form in a .html page and post to a php script.